# ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, importerror

When I try to import `psycopg2` it show below log for me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Desktop/learn/python/webcatch/appserver/testpgsql.py", line 2, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "D:/Desktop/learn/python/webcatch/appserver/webcatch/lib/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.1-py3.5-win32.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

How can I solve it?
My platform is win10 (64) and version is python 3.5

Comment: how did you install `psycopg2`? it didn't successfully install when i used `pip install psycopg2` so it may be specific to how it was installed.

Comment: i follow this [site](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) to install it on my computer

Comment: can you check `import psycopg2` in your python console? and check `sys.path` see whether the module path can be found or not?

Comment: i just see **_psycopg.cp35-win_amd64.py** and **_psycopg1.py** but don't have  **psycopg2._psycopg**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eureka! I pulled my hair out for 2 days trying to get this to work. Enlightenment came from [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146886/cant-install-psycopg-on-windows-7-with-python-3-4-3-and-postgresql-9-4-4). Simply stated, you probably installed psycopg2 x64 version like I did, not realizing your python version was 32-bit. Unistall your current psycopg2, then:

**Download**: *psycopg2-2.6.1.win32-py3.4-pg9.4.4-release.exe* from [HERE](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/), then run the following in a Terminal:

```
C:\path\to\project> easy_install /path/to/psycopg2-2.6.1.win32-py3.4-pg9.4.4-release.exe
C:\path\to\project> python manage.py makemigrations
C:\path\to\project> python manage.py migrate
```

You may also need to (re)create super user with:

```
C:\path\to\project> python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what finally solved a day and a half's worth of frustration. I only had to run 'easy_install' with the 32-bit psycopg2 version. I didn't have to run the makemigrations/migrate stuff. Cheers!

Comment: I'm using python 3.6, I just downloaded the .exe from [here](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) and installed it the normal widows way...
As am using **pip** and not **easy_install**

Comment: This is not just windows or cpu arch related but it depends also on the python version used to compile the package, even if psycopg2 is compiled with another version of python you could hit this problem.
Just compiled with 3.6 and was running on 3.7 and had this problem :/

Comment: @MattiaProcopio You do have to install the correct version based on what you are using, and it looks like 3.7 is yet to be supported by the stickpeople.com developer.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, solved it in this way:

Reinstall the package `psycopg2` using `pip` (by default installed with python 3)

On Linux:

> pip uninstall psycopg2

Confirm with (y) and then:

> pip install psycopg2

On Windows I add the prefix `('python -m')` to the commands above.
I think the problem occurs when you change the version of Python. (Even between minor versions such as Python 3.5 and 3.6).

Comment: This definitely helped me who recently switched from Python 3.7 to 3.8

Comment: Great Solution! I just switched from python 3.8 to python 3.9 today, and I occurred this problem... Thank you...

Comment: Thanks!  I just upgraded from 3.10.4 to 3.11.1 and had to execute the above in order for Django to work properly.

Answer (score 14):

I am using psycopg in an AWS Glue Job, where is harder to follow the instructions listed in the other answers.

What I did is installing psycopg2-binary into a directory and zip up the contents of that directory:

```
mkdir psycopg2-binary
cd psycopg2-binary
pip install psycopg2-binary -t  .
# in case using python3:
# python3 -m pip install --system psycopg2-binary -t  .
zip -r9 psycopg2.zip *
```

I then copied psycopg2.zip  to an S3 bucket and add it as an extra Python library under "Python library path" in the Glue Spark job.

I then launched the job with the following script to verify if psycopg2 is present (the zip file will be downloaded by Glue into the directory in which the Job script is located)

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import sys
import os
import zipfile

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('./psycopg2.zip', 'r')
print(os.listdir('.'))
zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/packages')
zip_ref.close()
sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/packages')

import psycopg2
print(psycopg2.__version__)

job.commit()
```

Comment: this worked for me as well.  Thanks for the code sample

Answer (score 12):

Download the compiled version of psycopg2 from this link https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2. As psycopg2 is C library for python, which need to be compiled on linux to make it work. The compile instruction also given on that link. Thanks to the https://github.com/jkehler.

Comment: I don't think OP was using AWS Lambda, but if you are, this is definitely the way to do it! Thanks!!

Comment: can we pip install?

Answer (score 6):

This also happens to me in new Ubuntu 18.04. It is caused by missing one file _psycopg.py in the /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2.

It is fixed by:

1. remove the old psycopg2 from your machine `pip3 uninstall psycopg2`.
2. download new pyscopg2 manually from the [official page](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) http://initd.org/psycopg/tarballs/PSYCOPG-2-7/psycopg2-2.7.7.tar.gz
3. `tar xvf psycopg2-2.7.7.tar.gz`
4. `python setup.py build`
5. `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04, with Python 3.9, after downloading sources psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz.
`python setup.py build` ran fine, but to install I needed `sudo python3 setup.py install`.

Answer (score 2):

For lambda functions on Python 3.7, I ended up using the `psycopg2-binary` library mentioned in these threads:

https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2/issues/51

[Using psycopg2 with Lambda to Update Redshift (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607952/using-psycopg2-with-lambda-to-update-redshift-python)

```
pip3 install psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
```

Snippet from these links:

`I ended up using a different library: psycopg2-binary in my requirement.txt file and it working fine now.`

`solved it by using psycopg2-binary==2.8.3`

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen in Linux using Python 3.7.  It is caused by missing one file _psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in the /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2.
I downloaded _psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so from https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2/tree/master/psycopg2-3.7, and Copied this file into my anaconda lib.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen in Linux using Python 2 because I had accidentally had my PYTHONPATH set to Python 3 libraries, and it was trying to load the python3 version of psycopg2. Solution was to `unset PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on Windows, this worked for me:
pip install -U psycopg2

I had an older version installed, must have depreciated

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that most times the WINDOWS packaging does not go fine with LAMBDA.

I faced same issue while running LAMBDA with WINDOWS installed 3rd party `pscyopg2` packaging.

#### Solution:

step1>
I installed `psycopg2` in Linux.
Copied both the directories `psycopg2_binary-2.8.2.dist-info` and `psycopg2` from Linux to windows.

step2>
Along with source `*.py`, packaged with copied 3rd party dependencies `psycopg2` in windows to `*.zip` file

step3>
Upload the file to LAMBDA - Here it goes, It runs successfully without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 with `conda` environment manager (fresh install of `Django`, `wagtail` with `PostgreSQL`), had the same error. Removed `psycopg2`

```
conda remove -n myenv psycopg2
```

it updated some packages, removed others (it also removed django, wagtail...). Then installed `psycopg2` back

```
conda install -n myenv psycopg2
```

Tested it, import worked

```
python
>>> import psycopg2
```

Installed `django`, `wagtail` back. `python manage.py migrate` now populated `PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was other site-packages that was exposed by installing `pgcli`, uninstalling `pgcli` resolved the issue for the time being.

*This somehow penetrated virtualenv too.*