# AWS Lambda Function Can't Find Package - Psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

Here's my issue:

```
START RequestId: 3ef6bbb9-62da-11e8-82ba-81e0afb0b224 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'lambda_insertEmailAddress': No module named psycopg2

END RequestId: 3ef6bbb9-62da-11e8-82ba-81e0afb0b224
REPORT RequestId: 3ef6bbb9-62da-11e8-82ba-81e0afb0b224  Duration: 0.44 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB
```

My zip file has the following structure `file name: lambdaInsertEmail.zip`:

```
 total 98784
drwxrwxrwx  20 chauncey  staff   680B May 27 13:22 psycopg2
drwxrwxrwx  22 chauncey  staff   748B May 27 12:55 postgresql-9.4.3
-rwxrwxrwx   1 chauncey  staff   1.8K Apr 30 15:41 lambda_insertEmailAddress.py
-rw-r--r--   1 chauncey  staff    48M May 30 12:09 lambdaInsertEmail.zip
```

In case you want to know my setup.cfg file has the following changes:

```
pg_config=/Users/chauncey/Desktop/portfolio/aws_lambda_files/lambda_insertEmailAddress/postgresql-9.4.3/src/bin/pg_config/pg_config

static_libpq=1
```

I'm trying to get this lambda function working.

Comment: What OS did you use to package the function? - note: Lambda will only be able to load psycopg2 if packaged in Linux. Also What version of python are you using?

Comment: @Jeff I used OSX 11.6.  I used the Terminal application.  The version of Python I used is 2.7.9.  Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try using the Amazon Linux AMI to compile the libraries? - reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/36608956/5787099

Comment: I'm trying to do that.  I'm getting this error:  `make[1]: *** [install-include-recurse] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/lambdaFunctions/postgresql-9.4.3/src'
make: *** [install-src-recurse] Error 2` on the make install.  How can I get this to work, using I guess the root password or sudo.  I tried `sudo make install` but it's not working.  I guess I need to switch to root but I don't know the password.

Comment: I actually made this happen by using `sudo su` and `sudo sh` and it didn't work.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

**The problem** is being cause because `psycopg2` needs to be build an compiled with statically linked libraries for Linux. Please reference [Using psycopg2 with Lambda to Update Redshift (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36607952/5787099) for more details on this issue. Another [reference](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217796) of problems of compiling `psycopg2` on OSX.

**One Solution** is to compile the library using an Amazon Linux AMI. Once you have connected to the AMI with SSH:

1. Set up aws credentials using aws configure
2. `sudo su -`
3. `pip install psycopg2 -t /path/to/project-dir`
4. Zip directory `zip project-dir.zip project-dir`
5. [Upload to Lambda using CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html)

Hopefully this helps you understand the issue and a possible solution solution. There are additional solutions in the above references, such as using `boto3` or this repo https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2, but this is the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

fixed it for me