# Building lambda function to connect to Postgresql getting :Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am testing my api gateway to call lambda function.
i was successful in the test.

i was then trying to make a connection to postgresql through the same lambda

```
   import json
   import psycopg2
    
    db_host = "hostname"
    db_port = 5432
    db_name ="db name"
    db_user ="user"
    db_pass ="password"
    
    def connect():
        conn = None
        try :
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={} user={} host={} password={}".format(db_name,db_user,db_host,db_pass))
    except :
        print("connetion error")
    return conn


print("Loading function")
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # paring query from the string 
    name = event['queryStringParameters']['name']
    action = event['queryStringParameters']['action']

print('name = '+name )
print('action = '+action)

# body of the response object 

transactionResponse = {}
transactionResponse['name'] = name
transactionResponse['action'] = action
transactionResponse['message'] = 'Lambda called from api_gateway'

# construting Http response

responseObject = {}
responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
responseObject['headers'] {}
responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(transactionResponse)

#  return the response object 

return responseObject
```

when i tried to trigger it through the API endpoint i got

```
 Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'psycopg2'
```

then i went ahead and build my lambda function by downloading the required package and then uploaded a zip file .

when i try to call try the same to trigger the lambda i am getting

```
 Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'
```

don't know what lamda_function is .

Could any one suggest me out of this slump ?
or
provide me a way to connect to RDS through lambda from API gateway trigger

This is my build Package
[image]

Answer (score 3):

the issue is no longer there.
Get the psycopg2 build library from https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2 was built for python 3.6 and make sure you change the name to psycopg2 while uploading your code to AWS lambda, select Python Runtime environment as 3.6, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the lambda handler name from the console. This is likely to be caused because the handler name is referring to `lambda_function.foobar` but the filename of the Lambda within the zip would be not be named `lambda_function.py`.

Ensure the name is in the format `filename.function_name`.

In this example if the file was named `lambda_function` then the handler value should be `lambda_function.lambda_handler`.

The directory structure does not currently include the `psycopg2` module so this will still not be able to be loaded.

To solve this the following solutions are applicable:

- Add the dependency via pip install, then zip up again deploy
- Add a Lambda layer with this dependency already installed

Comment: i added the lambda handler. seems to be working 
but I am getting this error 
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_api': No module named 'psycopg2'

Comment: How is this bundled with the Lambda?

Comment: created a folder with my lambda_api.py
and ran pip install requests -t .

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of contents on the files/directories relevant to what you zip? :)

Comment: how can i share a screen shoot here ?

Comment: If you upload in your question :)

Comment: have added it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217460/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-sumanth-shetty).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the [lambda_handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) settings and ensure they are correctly set to represent your function:

[image]

Comment: it worked but now i am getting 
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_api': No module named 'psycopg2'

Comment: @sumanthshetty Glad to hear. Have you bundled the `psycopg2` with your deployment package?

Comment: have added the image in the question

Comment: @sumanthshetty I don't see `psycopg2`  in your screenshot. You mean need to add it, for example as [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60818205/248823).

Comment: i have added it now .

now when I run I get the error 

Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_api': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

Comment: @sumanthshetty Maybe it got incorrectly installed. There is also [aws-psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/aws-psycopg2/). Maybe you can try that.

Comment: @sumanthshetty You can also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607952/using-psycopg2-with-lambda-to-update-redshift-python). Lots of useful info on how to use psycopg2 with lambda.

Comment: i tried installing the aws-psycopg2 but the zip is exceeding 10mb

Comment: @sumanthshetty Max allowed size of the zip is 50 MB, so I don't see why 10 MB would be a problem?