# error while uploading python zip file with psycopg2 to aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm trying to add the python zip files to was lambda which contains psycopg2 files in it.I'm getting an error. please try to help

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler': libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using psycopg2 with Lambda to Update Redshift (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607952/using-psycopg2-with-lambda-to-update-redshift-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point is psycopg2 depends on native code (libpq.so) and your zip file does not contain this dependency.

See [here](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2) for a solution

Another option is `pip install psycopg2-binary`. See [here](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this error on GitHub Actions with following code:

```yaml
- name: Package Lambda function
  run: |
    mkdir package
    cp main.py package/
    pip install psycopg2-binary -t package/
    pip install -r requirements.txt -t package/
    cd package
    zip -r ../function.zip .
    cd ..
```