# ImportError with psycopg2, Python 3.X

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, importerror

I am getting the error

```
  File "C:/Users/sssaliba/Documents/python playground/fdsa.py", line 9, in <module>
    import psycopg2

  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID

ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

When I run

```
import psycopg2
```

I have gone through the pip installation and double checked to make sure the files are within my python path.  I also took a look at:

[ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103034/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2-psycopg)

However, I am using 64bit python.  Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a 32bit version of python in addition to the 64 Ipython I use.  When the pip installer ran, it installed 32bit psycopg2 instead of 64bit, which didn't work on Ipython.  Essentially the opposite of the question posted.