# Not able to install psycopg2 using pip install psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, django-rest-framework, psycopg2

I am trying to link postgresSQL with my django framework.
My db settings in settings.py are

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'tutorial',
        'USER': 'vibhor',
        'PASSWORD': 'vibhor',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I ran `pip install psycopg2` and it got installed successfully. But when I run the program, I faced the error below. I am using python version 3.7.2 on windows 10 Enterprise

I am getting same error again and again -

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'`

Comment: See basically [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103034/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2-psycopg)

Comment: Thanks @Guillem, that post helped me resolve my problem