# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

Tags: python, windows, psycopg2

I am using imports :-
**import psycopg2**

But while running the code in local, I am facing an issue of :-

**from psycopg2._psycopg import (**

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'**

I have installed psycopg2 using cmd [pip install psycopg2]
psycopg2 version 2.8.4
python version 3.7.3
python 3.7 32bit

How should I import the ._psycopg.py file in windows? or any other solution if possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2.\_psycopg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103034/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2-psycopg)

Comment: No . I have already seen it but none is working. However how can i see which psycopg2 version is enabled for python 3.7 32 bit ?

Comment: Try `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: Try using that. Go here:http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/psycopg/&ved=2ahUKEwjYw7zJ2MvoAhUnzzgGHTm0CFMQFjABegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1k6ZJ3IHLTZwmVObfXCIll

Comment: same error with psycopg2-binary also !!

Comment: Did you try get what you want from http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/psycopg/&ved=2ahUKEwjYw7zJ2MvoAhUnzzgGHTm0CFMQFjABegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1k6ZJ3IHLTZwmVObfXCIll

Answer (score 2):

I'm also facing the same problem. It took me 2 days to pulled out my hair until I found the solution.

#### What I've been tried

Here's what I have been doing to solve this issue **BUT DIDN'T SOLVE THE PROBLEM**. I hope it will help anybody else who has the same problem.

1. Install "psycopg2" and "psycopg2-binary"

   - `pip install psycopg2`
   - `pip install psycopg2-binary`
2. Install "libpq-dev"

   - `sudo apt install libpq-dev`
3. Install "python-psycopg2" and "python3-psycopg2"

   - `sudo apt install python-psycopg2 python3-psycopg2`
4. Install "python-dev" and "python3-dev" and "python3.9-dev"

   - `sudo apt install python-dev python3-dev python3.9-dev`
5. Install "python-setuptools"

   - `sudo apt install python-setuptools`

Unfortunately, none of my effort above solve my problem.

---

#### What's the solution

So, here's my solution that I've been try and **IT WORKS**

**Install the latest mod_wsgi from Github.**

You should install this latest 'mod_wsgi' in order to your wsgi able to use Psycopg2 library. Here's my step to do it :

1. Go to release page mod_wsgi on Github (https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases)
2. Download the file from latest version. As I write this, the latest version is 4.7.1 (https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.7.1.tar.gz)
3. Follow the installation guide from official docs.

   1. [Unpacking source code](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#unpacking-the-source-code)

      - `tar xvfz mod_wsgi-4.7.1.tar.gz`
   2. [Configure source code](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#configuring-the-source-code)

      - `./configure`
   3. [Build the source code and install](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#building-the-source-code)

      - `make`
      - `make install`
   4. [Restart apache server](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#restart-apache-web-server)

      - `sudo service apache2 restart`

This solution has works on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04 & Python 3.9 Venv).

---

#### Alternative solution

Here's some solution from others.

1. [Saray Chak's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54938193/4494207)