# How to fix psycop2 importation not working, after it being installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, postgresql, psycopg2

I pip installed psycopg2, with it's requirements

```
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in ./virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.8.6)
```

However, when i import it i'm getting this error.

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'.
```

Also i am on a linux operating system.

Comment: can you add  code or content of file you trying to excute ?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006302/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-psycopg2-psycopg , please read this and see if it solve your problem