# Jupyter note book ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' while Requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2, anaconda3

I worked this issue for 2 days:
when I import psycopg2 into jupter notebook,it always return:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7d2da0a5d979> in <module>
----> 1 import psycopg2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

I have used all the way no matter pip or conda to install both psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary but none of them works for me.

I'm using MAC and python version in anaconda is python 3.9

Any one can help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'psycopg2.\_psycopg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006302/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-psycopg2-psycopg)

Answer (score 1):

first, u have to download the library.
using this command in juypter notebook.
--> conda install psycopg2
make sure you have an internet connection
then u have to wait for 1-2 min it automatically downloads the library.
then u can use that

Comment: I have tried this way, not work.

Comment: Please, fix the formatting and grammar accordningly

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem (albeit on Linux) but everything worked flawlessly.

Because your workflow for creating and using the Jupyter Notebook is not super-clear, it might be a good idea to run the code that worked for me and see whether it helps:

```bash
# Install packages from conda-forge (usually the best choice and very up-to-date packages)
conda create --name test python=3.9 jupyterlab psycopg2 -c conda-forge
# activate the new environment
conda activate test
# Start Jupyterlab
jupyter-lab
```

After testing you can remove the environment like so

```bash
conda deactivate
conda env remove --name test
```

Let me know whether it helped :-)