# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

Tags: python, postgresql, pip

I am using Python 3.7 and trying to use psycopg2 in my program.
Only one line of code so far.

```py
import psycopg2
```

I looked at various approaches given on Stack Overflow but didn't find anything helpful.

```
pip uninstall psycopg2

pip install psycopg2

pip install psycopg2-binary -t  .
```

Comment: Are you sure `pip` is for Python3?  What if you do `pip3 install psycopg2`?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103034/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2-psycopg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python3, then you should use pip3 for installing packages:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

By default, pip is for python-pip package and python2, and pip3 is for python3-pip package and python3. unless you have an alias that pip=pip3

Answer (score 0):

Another potential issue that often causes ModuleNotFoundError issues is if you name your script the same as the module you're trying to import. In this case, check if your program is named `psycopg2`.

The solution is to rename your script to a name which doesn't conflict with the names of the imported modules.