# "All requested packages already installed" but "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, conda, psycopg2

I'm running python 3.9 and my goal is to install and import pyscopg2:

```
python --version 
Python 3.9.12

conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/doug/anaconda3
```

Looks like I'm in anaconda base env.

```
conda install psycopg2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Now, when I try to import:

Enter python terminal:

```
python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 06:56:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Then try to import:

```
import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/doug/Documents/Projects/Zen/Projects/data-scripts/ga4ExtractLoad/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36103034/494134

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2.\_psycopg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103034/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2-psycopg)

Comment: @JohnGordon that post and accepted answer seems to be more about windows. I'm on Linux. I tried other suggestions on there like uninstalling and then reinstalling but my problem persists

Comment: In case the installed directory is not in the library path, you can use find -iname in the installed target directory find the specific location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `/home/doug/Documents/Projects/Zen/Projects/data-scripts/ga4ExtractLoad/psycopg2` is masking what is installed into your `base` environment.

Try running this import from a different directory and/or delete `/home/doug/Documents/Projects/Zen/Projects/data-scripts/ga4ExtractLoad/psycopg2`.

See [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73882861/5239932)